# Date time interpretation for Work& break time calculation

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I extracted the data from csv and converted to below format after data preparation with python.
I want to further prepare as below to store it as table in DB.

If we see below table, 8th hour from 0 min to 52 min its working time (Status:1)
from 8th hour from 53min to 59min its break (snacks break)(Status:2)

How do i convert it.

```
Existing
+------+-------+------------+------+------+------+----------+--------+--------+-------+-----+
|      | plant |    date    | shop | line | hour | startmin | endmin | status | shift | uph |
+------+-------+------------+------+------+------+----------+--------+--------+-------+-----+
|    8 | HEF1  | 03-01-2020 | E    |    1 |    8 |        0 |     52 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
|    9 | HEF1  | 03-01-2020 | E    |    1 |    8 |       53 |     59 |      2 |     2 |  25 |
|   10 | HEF1  | 03-01-2020 | E    |    1 |    9 |        0 |     59 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
|   11 | HEF1  | 03-01-2020 | E    |    1 |   10 |        0 |     59 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| 9645 | HEF2  | 27-01-2020 | E    |    1 |    7 |        0 |     59 |      1 |     1 |  58 |
| 9646 | HEF2  | 27-01-2020 | E    |    1 |    8 |        0 |     52 |      1 |     1 |  58 |
| 9647 | HEF2  | 27-01-2020 | E    |    1 |    8 |       53 |     59 |      2 |     1 |  58 |
+------+-------+------------+------+------+------+----------+--------+--------+-------+-----+
```

I want to convert it to as below

```
Required
+-------+---------------------+------+------+------+--------+-------+-----+
| plant |      datetime       | shop | line | hour | status | shift | uph |
+-------+---------------------+------+------+------+--------+-------+-----+
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:00:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:01:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:02:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:03:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:04:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:05:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:06:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:07:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:08:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:09:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:10:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:11:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:12:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:13:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:14:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:15:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:16:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:17:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:18:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:19:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:20:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:21:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:22:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:23:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:24:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:25:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:26:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:27:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:28:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:29:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:30:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:31:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:32:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:33:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:34:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:35:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:36:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:37:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:38:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:39:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:40:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:41:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:42:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:43:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:44:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:45:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:46:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:47:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:48:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:49:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:50:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:51:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:52:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |

| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:53:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      2 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:54:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      2 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:55:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      2 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:56:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      2 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:57:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      2 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:58:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      2 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 08:59:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      2 |     2 |  25 |

| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 09:00:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
| HEF1  | 03-01-2020 09:01:00 | E    |    1 |    8 |      1 |     2 |  25 |
+-------+---------------------+------+------+------+--------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create begin and end timestamps:

```
df['start_ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) +' '+ df['hour'].astype(str)+':'+df['startmin'].astype(str))
df['end_ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) +' '+ df['hour'].astype(str)+':'+df['endmin'].astype(str))
```

Then create a date range column:

```
df['t_range'] = [pd.date_range(start=x[0], end=x[1], freq='min') for x in zip(df['start_ts'], df['end_ts'])]
```

Then explode by that column:

```
df.explode('t_range')
```

delete and rename columns as needed